# .bat rename files name remove first x characters and last x characters

Tags: batch-file

I need to rename files in some folder, like explained it needs to rename file names in one folder by removing first number of x characters and last number of x characters I set. 
Can someone show me how to do that?

Comment: If you're simply looking for a useful tool to do fancy rename operations from the command line, have a look at this Perl script (doing it in a batch file is ugly and error prone): http://greenfly.net/rename

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=3
set FOLDER_PATH=.
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    set "filename=!filename:~%X%,-%X%!"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
```

This script enters the folder (specified by `FOLDER_PATH`) and trims the first and last `X` characters from the *filename* of each file (leaving its extension as is). Modify `X` and `FOLDER_PATH` as necessary.

Comment: What if we would like only to remove last X characters of all files with .mdb extension in a folder?

Comment: @NT01 Then replace the line `set "filename=!filename:~%X%,-%X%!"` (inside the loop) with this one: `set "filename=!filename:~,-%X%!"`