# Batch file that removes first 6 characters of filename in directory

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm looking to create a batch file that removes the first 6 characters of all files in a folder.  Please can someone help?

Comment: Use search before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.bat rename files name remove first x characters and last x characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410982/bat-rename-files-name-remove-first-x-characters-and-last-x-characters)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET targetFolder=C:\Path\To\Target\Dir
FOR /R %%f in (%targetFolder%\*) DO (
    SET "oldName=%%~nxf"
    SET "newName=!oldName:~6!"
    MOVE /Y "%targetFolder%\!oldName!" "%targetFolder%\!newName!"
)
PAUSE
```

The key line is `SET "newName=!oldName:~6!"`. After this command `%newLine%` contains the old name without the first 6 characters.

Comment: Thanks for response. I get an error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: Can't be. You must have missed something. For me it works just fine. Please post your whole code.

Comment: Had a space in file path.  Don't get error now but don't get the result.

Comment: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET targetFolder=C:\test
for /r %%f in (%targetFolder%\*) DO (
    SET oldName=%%~nxf
    SET newName=!oldName:~6!
    MOVE /Y %targetFolder%\!oldName! %targetFolder%\!newName!
)
PAUSE

Comment: \ is missing here: %targetFolder%*! It must be %targetFolder%\*!

Comment: change **for /r %%f in (%targetFolder%*)** to **for /r "%targetFolder%" %%f in ("*")** and **MOVE /Y %targetFolder%\!oldName! %targetFolder%\!newName!** to **ren "%%f" "!newName!"**. This will work with path and file name with space.

Comment: Always quote where appropriate, please. The `set` commands would be broken by `&` in file names; the `move` command would be broken by spaces in file names.

Answer (score 0):

Final Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET targetFolder=C:\Test
for /r "%targetFolder%" %%f in ("*") DO (
    SET oldName=%%~nxf
    SET newName=!oldName:~6!
    ren "%%f" "!newName!"
)

PAUSE
```