# Remove 'x' Characters at Beginning of File Name Using Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I frequently burn CD's, download music, movies, etc, and one thing that almost all the files have are some numbers in the beginning of each file name designating order. ("01.FILE_1, 02.FILE_2"...) Using a batch file I would really like to be able to remove the first x amount of characters (3 in this case), so it would go from "05.FILE_5" to "FILE_5."

On this thread: 
[.bat rename files name remove first x characters and last x characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11410982/bat-rename-files-name-remove-first-x-characters-and-last-x-characters/11411809#11411809?newreg=439f5375baac4d9bbbf78c95b7bdbc9d)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=3
set FOLDER_PATH=.
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    set "filename=!filename:~%X%,-%X%!"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
```

I found instructions for removing first AND last characters, but I can't figure out how to modify the code for just the initial characters.

Thanks so much for the help!, I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll have much more fun (and better answers too :) if you show what you tried so far. In the example you linked, Have you tried  playing with the `set` part inside the `for`?

Comment: Yeah, I played around mainly with the second line in the set part. Someone asked on the original thread how to delete just the LAST characters, so I tried doing kind of the opposite of what the guy responded with. (Not really the opposite, but more playing around with the other part.) No luck, I'm not really familiar with batch syntax so it was pretty much guess and check.

Comment: What about splitting off everything up to the first `.` in your file names (`set "filename=!filename:*.=!"`)? or do you always have exactly three characters to remove?

Answer (score 3):

You should modify the answer by Eitan T like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=3
set FOLDER_PATH=.
pushd %FOLDER_PATH%
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    set "filename=!filename:~%X%!"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
```

See [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) for more information about variable substrings

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for